# Term for a smallish program built on top a larger library/framework?

Tags: terminology

What exactly do you call a relatively smallish program/application built on top a larger library/framework?

The small program (foo) in question does a whole lot but much of the heavy lifting is done by the library (bar) on top of which this program is built. When I say that I designed/developed 'foo' with such and such capabilities I do not want to convey the wrong idea that I coded everything, including the low level stuff, all by myself.

Edit: Just to clarify, this is a numerical code built on top of a numerical library.

Comment: I'd call it a good application. Maybe you can invent a name.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR, almost nobody is going to think you invented everything. If they do, it's a good opportunity to educate them high-level information about computers and software architecture.

In general, this is just an application, utility, or tool. Your runtime context may throw in additional adjectives (e.g. command-line tool, web application, etc).

I think your worries regarding attribution are probably unfounded. If your project is open source, your documentation will certainly need to list the build and runtime dependencies. If there are different licenses, you'll likely also have to ship those with your tool. So it's unlikely that anyone other than people entirely unfamiliar with software engineering would get the "wrong idea".

Furthermore, nearly every software package is built on top of some sort of toolkit. For example, even basic utilities like `ls`, `cp`, etc. are built on top of the standard C library and make use of system calls provided by the operating system. Indeed, without the OS, such utilities have no runtime environment in which to execute. The OS has nothing to do if there is no hardware for it to manage (and even some of that hardware is likely to have firmware -- which is just software-on-chip -- to control some of its behavior regardless of an operating system).

The higher up the stack you move, the harder it becomes for someone to mistake the work you did versus the work you built upon. A web application needs an HTTP server, possibly a module interface or CGI environment, a language to express the intent of the software, etc. And then all of this is built on top of the OS, which goes down to hardware, some firmware, etc.

Finally, even if the library does the heavy lifting, that doesn't detract from the value of your software. If your software does a number of very useful things, it doesn't matter whether the library enabled your software to do those things. Some of the most important inventions in history are super simple in retrospect. It just took someone to see how to combine the parts in a different way. This is effectively what we do with software.

If someone does seem to get the wrong idea, this is perhaps a good time to educate them about the complexities of computing environments, the interrelationships between software components, the software stack, etc. It also might be fine to just let it slide and say, "Thank you!"